# Django add custom permission

Tags: python, django

I am facing the problem of adding custom permission in Django. My idea is that when authorizing a user, if it belongs to group1, only the rows of group1 are displayed, and otherwise the rows of group2. There is a group field in the database table, it contains only two values group1 and group2. In the admin panel, I created 2 groups, respectively, and also included users in these groups. Also I created permissions and assigned them to each user.

My models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
   DEPT =(
    ('Group1', 'Group1'),
    ('Group2', 'Group2')
   )

   dept = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=DEPT, default='')
   fio = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
   work_place = models.CharField(max_length = 150, default= '')

def __str__(self):
    return self.fio

class Meta:
    permissions = (
                   ("view_museum", "can view museum"),
                   ("view_ssoismi", "can view ssoismi"),
                  )
```

My views.py

```
def employee_list(request):
   context = {'employee_list': Employee.objects.all()}
   return render(request, "employee_register/employee_list.html", context)
```

If i change the context row to

```
context = {'employee_list': Employee.objects.filter(dept="Group1")}
```

I get the desired result, but how can do it automatically with django groups and etc.
Maybe i do something wrong?
Any idea what to do next?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the admin panel, I created 2 groups, respectively, and also included users in these groups.

Query these group names by filtering `request.user.groups` with `name__in`. Then filter `Employee.objects` by those results with `dept__in`.

Note that this assumes the admin group names are named exactly like the `Employee.dept` field. If not, rename the admin groups to match the `Employee.dept` field (including capitalization, spaces, etc.).

```py
def employee_list(request):
    groups = [g.name for g in request.user.groups.filter(name__in=['Group1', 'Group2')]
    context = {'employee_list': Employee.objects.filter(dept__in=groups)}

    return render(request, 'employee_register/employee_list.html', context)
```

Comment: I have one more question. If a user belongs to both groups, how can I assign user to both groups?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
context = {'employee_list': Employee.objects.filter(dept=request.user.group)}
```

I'm not sure how you made the User belong in one of the groups but I'm guessing you also have a `group` field on your User model.

Comment: I didn't even create a User group by myself. I think i'm using the standard one from the library. Can please explain, how can I properly do this thing?